# How to use CustomJS in BokehJS?

Tags: javascript, plot, callback, bokeh

As BokehJS is relatively new, I am struggling to find a working example showing CustomJS usage with BokehJS. I expect things to be different from using CustomJS in python as is should be possible to provide directly a javascript function as argument to CustomJS in BokehJS instead of a javascript code snippet when using [CustomJS](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-callbacks) in python.

In the absence of any further information, my best guess was the following bit of code which is meant to print in the console the lower bound of the x axis whenever it is updated upon panning or zooming user action, and it does not work.

Can anyone correct this and show the correct usage of CustomJS in BokehJS?

EDIT: Example updated using solution provided on Github. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.10.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.10.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.10.js"></script>
    <!-- The order of CSS and JS imports above is important. -->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="myPlot">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // data to plot
    var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
        data: { x: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], y: [0,1,4,-2,2,5,0,2,1,1] }
    });

    // make the plot and add some tools
    var tools = "pan,crosshair,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save";

    var plot = Bokeh.Plotting.figure({
        title:"demo plot",
        tools: tools,
        toolbar_location:"above",
        sizing_mode:"stretch_both"
    });

    var scatterData = plot.line({ field: "x" }, { field: "y" }, {
        source: source,
        line_width: 2
    });

    plot.x_range.callback=new Bokeh.CustomJS({args:{plot:plot},code:"console.log(plot.x_range.start);"});

    // Show the plot, appending it to the end of the current
    // section of the document we are in.
    Bokeh.Plotting.show(plot,document.getElementById("myPlot"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was discussed here:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7130

Current proper usage shown in edited code from the question.

Starting from Bokeh 0.12.11, it will also be possible to define callback on range directly as javascript functions:

```
plot.x_range.callback=function(){console.log(plot.x_range.start);};
```